# How To display notification in iphone that an incoming call is being forwarded from an outside line

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, notifications

I want to create an iPhone application which will display notification that an incoming call is being forwarded from an outside line, to my iPhone.

Purpose being, I have 3 separate office land lines that forward calls to my cell phone after hours and I would like to know from which they are coming from.

is there any possible way ? Kindly help,thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to do this at all on an iPhone unless it's jailbroken. How is it being forwarded?

Comment: Hi CeeJayoz thanks for the Reply. The call is being forwarded automatically from the land lines  and the Iphone shows normal incoming notification.But I would like to know from which line they are coming from.and the device is not jailbroken.

Comment: No, nothing different in iOS5 for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an unjailbroken phone, you cannot interfere with incoming calls in any way.

On a jailbroken phone, your ability to do this depends on the phone system that's doing the call forwarding.