# How can I set up a notification on a jailbroken iphone that the incoming call is forwarded from an outside line?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, forward

I wanted to comment on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253398/how-to-display-notification-in-iphone-that-an-incoming-call-is-being-forwarded-f/10253598#10253598?newreg=56b4ccd91c764712a1a63245f1d8da3d) but I don't have the credentials yet to leave comments, so I will pose it as a brand new question.

In the aforementioned answer, the user states that the differentiation between inbound calls which are forwarded from an outside line and those that are not IS possible with a jailbroken iPhone (but not possible otherwise). What jailbroken apps exist that address this issue?

(I just need to be able to assess when to answer the phone professionally and when to answer it personally.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you asking which apps can do this, or how would you **code** an app to do this?  If it's the former, then the question would be off topic for Stack Overflow.  This is for programming questions, only.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was for coding only. I just saw someone here mentioned it was possible on a jailbroken phone, and I wanted to know how. I personally know nothing about coding apps.

Comment: If you have a non-coding question about jailbroken iPhones, I would recommend posting it somewhere like jailbreakqa.com.